# HTML5 data attribute vs value?

Tags: javascript, html

Besides semantics and browser support, is there any difference between the original value attribute, and the HTML5 data attribute?

```
<div id="mydiv" value="myvalue" data-somedata="mydata"></div>
```

Comment: Forgive me - what does `o.g.` stand for?

Comment: @MikeW Open Graph. See http://ogp.me/

Comment: Open Graph attributes are standardized. HTML5 `data-` attributes aren't.

Comment: my bad - the o.g. I was referencing is "original gansta".  I'll just go clarify/delete that now...

Comment: @calipoop The original gangster value? I don't think it has any support in IE :/

Comment: @Zenith - nice.  Lol'd.

Comment: `div` elements don't have a `value` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `value` is not a standard attribute for a `div` element so your html is not valid. If you want to honor html5 specification, you'll have to use `data-` attributes.

So in short: `data-` attributes is valid in html5 while your `value` approach is invalid on all html versions.

Comment: Wow - I had no idea value was not and never was standard.  Guess there's no reason not to use data- in it's place?

Comment: Oh - now I think I see, you're referring specifically to div elements.  I assume "value" is valid for form elements, etc.

Comment: The `value` attribute is not valid in `form` elements. Maybe you meant “form fields”, or controls, but among them, `value` is (as per HTML 4.01) valid only in `input` and `button` elements, not in `textarea` or `select`.